# Is it possible to create a "foreign key pair" ? - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables involved.I would like, in the third table, to ensure that a pair of keys in this table is present in the second one.

```
CATEGORY  
idc
```

-

```
CHILD_CATEGORY 
idcc
c_category_id
```

-

```
PLACE_CHILD_CATEGORY
idp
p_category_id
p_child_category_id
```

I would like to know if I can create a link that ensures that.

PLACE_CHILD_CATEGORY(p_category_id, p_child_category_id) combination exists in CHILD_CATEGORY(idcc, c_category_id)

Where :

p_child_category_id == idcc

et

p_category_id == c_category_id

Any way to do that ?

Comment: Just google for 'SQL JOIN 3 TABLES', and put your restrictions in the 'WHERE' clauses. (You can have more than 1 restriction.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, I will chose rims proposition because I want a restriction directly on table note for search results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE PLACE_CHILD_CATEGORY
  ADD FOREIGN KEY PLACE_CHILD_CATEGORY_fk (p_category_id, p_child_category_id)
  REFERENCES CHILD_CATEGORY (c_category_id, idcc)
```

More info: [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html); [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: It's as simple as that ?

Thanks a lot.